# Make fonts on Windows render like Mac/Linux: disabling font-hinting and/or deal with anti-alias on client side

Tags: windows, fonts, antialiasing, truetype, princexml

Is it possible to turn off "font-hinting" on Windows via javascript or any other client side code?

I want browsers on Windows to mimic fonts the way they look on Mac - because I'm using an HTML-to-PDF tool (PrinceXML) which I think is the best in the market so far but it renders fonts like a Mac. So what's happening is that Windows users will create HTML-based designs which will then get rendered by the PDF conversion tool. But the fonts will look different on the PDF than what they did in the Windows-based browser - I want them to look the same.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "renders fonts like a Mac", but Prince documentation [says](https://www.princexml.com/doc/6.0/fonts/) it uses Times New Roman, Arial and Courier New, and gives instructions on how to change this.