# Font hinting behavior in PhantomJS?

Tags: pdf, browser, fonts, phantomjs

I need to render text contained within `divs` on HTML document into PDF. I'm thinking of using PhantomJS, but one thing is very important. Different browsers and platforms render the text differently. So if I have the following code:

```
<div style='width:150px; height:80px; position:absolute; top:130px; left:78px'>
<p> Some text, yayy! :) </p>
</div>
```

It may render on one browser like this:

```
                              Some text, yayy!:)
```

But on another like this:

```
                              Some text, 
                              yayy!:)
```

What happened was that (because of font-hinting, I guess), the text in the first example ended up with a certain width that fit into the containing `div`, but because of the font rendering on the second browser, the text ended up taking just a little more space that didn't fit in the container, and had to wrap around to the next line. I can't afford this kind of unreliability on how the output turns out. If the HTML had it on one line, I need the PDF to have on the same line too.

I've actually asked a related question here: [Make fonts on Windows render like Mac/Linux: disabling font-hinting and/or deal with anti-alias on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670724/make-fonts-on-windows-render-like-mac-linux-disabling-font-hinting-and-or-deal) with no luck, but it was basically in trying to solve this same issue.

Can PhantomJS do anything about this? Or can PhantomJS at least somehow calculate the *true width* of a text, without font hinting and any other things involved? Or maybe calculate what it might render to if hinting were included? Or anything, as long as things come out on the PDF as they look on HTML. (Given the application I'm working on, I do not have the freedom change the CSS style of the containing `DIV`).

Comment: @Ariya Hidayat - hope you can respond here?

Answer (score 0):

Font hinting is almost certainly not what is changing the width of text here.  Font hinting involves making small adjustments to line up edges in an outline font to screen pixels; the adjustments are made within each character and should not change the overall width of that character.

Across platforms, there are slightly different *versions* of a font because of licensing issues.  macOS and GNU/Linux can't usually go out and copy Microsoft's fonts exactly, for legal reasons, so the nearest you'll get is a font that basically looks the same (and has a similar name) but isn't really the same font.  So some width variations across platforms are to be expected, unless you can provide your own font files along with the page (web fonts).

PhantomJS uses the system's fonts just like any other browser.  So using PhantomJS will not automatically give you some "cross-platform" set of fonts that's different from your system fonts.

If you need 100% reproducibility then I suggest creating a virtual machine (or Docker image) with a standard set of fonts installed, and use that everywhere.  Just don't forget to apply security patches to it when needed.